# AMD Radeon can not handle multiple monitors on a Dell Inspiron laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, radeon

My dual display will not work properly. The screen flickers and displays half in primary and half in secondary monitor.

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 7520 with dual video card: AMD Radeon HD 7730M and  Intel HD Graphics 4000. While on Intel card and Intel drivers, dual monitors had no problem.

Since I installed Radeon drivers using Catalyst Control Center whenever I connect the second monitor, the display is screwed: it displays one screen half on the first monitor and second on the other, the display is flickering whenever I move the mouse and other "special defects" take place. Catalyst is running driver version 14.301.1001, second driver: 14.30.4, Catalyst Control Center Version is 2.21 and RanrR version 1.3

Please advice,
Thanks

Comment: same issue with my HP ProBook 4540s

Comment: After 2 years I posted this problem, things are ok again. This was a drivers related issue. What I noticed is that not all releases of drivers work ok. I got used to install only the stable versions and avoid beta or optionals.